# Cube project doesn't work because of permissions

Tags: sql-server, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm doing "Multidimensional Project" with MS SQL Server 2012 (Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2010 Shell).  I can't run (debug) it.

If the data source's impersonation information is set to "use the service account", this error occures:

> Error 2   Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        0   0
>
> Error 3   OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.      0   0
>
> Error 4   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Data Warehouse', Name of 'Data Warehouse'.      0   0
>
> Error 5   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Items', Name of 'Items' was being processed.      0   0
>
> Error 6   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Id' attribute of the 'Items' dimension from the 'Warehouse_MultidimensionalProject_Cube' database was being processed.      0   0
> Error 7   Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.        0   0

I guessed that this account has no premissions but (1) I coudn't even add this account (it seems that it doesn't exist) and (2) how is that even possible for it to not have built-it poremissions?

When I'm setting impersonation to "use the credentials of current user" (which is the owner of the data source, btw.), another error occures:

> Error 2   Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        0   0
>
> Error 3   The datasource, 'Data Warehouse', contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations.        0   0
>
> Error 4   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Data Warehouse', Name of 'Data Warehouse'.      0   0
>
> Error 5   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Items', Name of 'Items' was being processed.      0   0
>
> Error 6   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Id' attribute of the 'Items' dimension from the 'Warehouse_MultidimensionalProject_Cube' database was being processed.      0   0
>
> Error 7   Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.        0   0

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password musn't be set to blank for SQL Server to work properly... curious detail. :-)